# Next delivery date listed on website

Tags: php

I'm building a website for a business that makes deliveries every second Thursday.  I need to display when the next delivery is going to be, and have that date change to two weeks forward when the previous delivery date is reached.

Based on what I've been able to research so far, I've cobbled together this code:

```
$start_date = '2016-10-27'; // next delivery date to start counting from

// create a DateTime object that represents start of sequence
$start_datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $start_date);

// create a DateTime object representing the current date
$current_datetime = new DateTime('today');
$date_interval = new DateInterval('P2W'); // for delivery every 2 weeks

// determine end date for DatePeriod object that will later be used
// this is no further out than current date plus the interval
$end_datetime = new DateTime('tomorrow');
$end_datetime->add($date_interval);

$date_period = new DatePeriod($start_datetime, $date_interval, $end_datetime);

// iterate until the last date in the set
foreach($date_period as $dp) {
    $next_delivery = $dp;
}
?>
<div class="header-next-delivery">
  Next delivery: <?php echo $next_delivery->format('l, M j, Y'); ?>
</div>
```

This seems to work, but I can't help thinking that there must be a more elegant way to do this than having to iterate through a set of dates from the start date to the last date in the set.  As time passes, the set will just get bigger and bigger.

Also, I'm having trouble figuring out the internal workings of these functions -- how would I set the exact time that the displayed delivery date bumps forward by two weeks?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Take a look at the Carbon library - it makes working with dates much much nicer. http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/ provides stuff like `->endOfWeek` and `->next(Carbon::THURSDAY)` for example

Comment: Instead of setting the $start_date to a fixed date, I think you could just get the current date. From what you described, you only care about the "next" 2nd Thursday, and don't care about previous ones. If your setup has a database connection, you could store the previous 2nd Thursday's date in there, or if not, you could write it to a file and then just read in the value when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

You can get date interval in days from $start_date to current date. Divide it by 14 (two weeks), get remainder and substract it from 14. Then you can add that value of days to current date.

```
$start_date = date_create('2016-10-27');
$current_date = date_create();
$interval = date_diff($start_date, $current_date);
$days_diff = (int)$interval->format('%a');

$current_date->add(14 - ($days_diff % 14).' days');
```